# Suggestions to improve storing and comparison of strings and chars

Tags: c, string

The problem goes like this.

Change the strings provided by user to form palindromes.
To do this, 2 rules are:
(a) Reduce the value of a letter, e.g. Change 'd' to 'c', but cannot change 'c' to 'd'. 
(b) In order to form a palindrome, you can repeatedly reduce the value of a letter until the letter becomes 'a'. Once a letter has been changed to 'a', it can no longer be changed.

Each reduction in the value of any letter is counted as a single operation. Find the minimum number of operations required to convert a given string into a palindrome.

This is a Hackerrank problem : "the-love-letter-mystery"

While i was solving it, i did lot of mistakes, i was using `char *str[n]` and `gets` to input the string. I thought it would work but i realised after long time that i am not actually allocating any space at all. Later i came up with 2-d array `char[n][1000]` for storing the strings and `scanf` seemed working for me.

Here is my solution:

```
int main() {


    int i, n, len, pos, ops, end;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    char str[n][10000];
    char a,b;
    for (i=0;i<n;i++) {
        scanf("%s",str[i]);
    }
    for (i=0;i<n;i++) {
        len = strlen(str[i]);
        pos = 0;
        end = len - 1;
        ops = 0;
        while ( pos < end) {
               a = str[i][pos];
               b = str[i][end];
               if ( a != b ) {
                   if ( b > a ) 
                       ops = ops + (b -a);
                   else 
                       ops = ops + (a -b); 
               }
               pos++;
               end--;    
        }
        printf("%d\n", ops);
    }

return 0;
}
```

This works perfectly.
Also i have to assume in the program that the strings can be of max length 1000 as that is one of the constraint.

How to improve this solution without making it too much complex ?
Suggestions of storing and comparing is what i am looking for.

Comment: What if the string length is 1001 characters? You should use `fgets()` or `scanf("%999s",str[i]);`, Variable `len` should be of `size_t`.

Comment: Max is 1000. can't be more than that according to the problem , but yeah you can suggest that kind of improvement as well.

Comment: Do you get an AC for this solution??

Comment: @1336087, Some explanation  with the suggestions will be great

Comment: Belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks will post it there @n.m

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can `#include <string.h>` and use `strcmp`/`strncmp` to compare strings.
Hard-coding lengths is risky : you need to control the length of your input with `fgets` (`#include <stdio.h>`).

Comment: strcmp will only return 1 or -1 or 0 right?? How can we calculate the difference in the strings???

Comment: @user007, `strcmp()` shall return an integer greater than, equal to, or less than 0